# Does global variable increase speed of compilation significantly in c++?

Tags: c++

For a problem

> https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/760/B

when i submitted solution having declaration inside int main() it shows TLE, but when declaration is above int main(), it's accepted in c++.

So my question is does global declaration affects the compilation speed significantly or i am missing something?

Here is the accepted one :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n,k,m,a=1,c=1;

int main()
{
    cin>>n>>m>>k;

    m -= n;
    while (m>0){

        if (k+a<=n) c++;
        if (k-a>=1) c++;
        m -=c;
        a++;
    }
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

here is TLE one :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,k,m,a=1,c=1;

    cin>>n>>m>>k;

    m -= n;
    while (m>0){

        if (k+a<=n) c++;
        if (k-a>=1) c++;
        m -=c;
        a++;
    }
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You worry about the effects that a global variable might have on compilation time, but [include the whole standard library, when you would only need `iostream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) :D

Comment: TLE is for execution. The compilation speed is not relevant. What optimizations is this program being run with?

Comment: @cigien I believe that online judge uses GCC with -O2.

Comment: It's probably because having the local variables in this case just happens to affect the way the compiler optimize your code and makes it a little slower. There shouldn't be any significant difference in general though.

Comment: Uugh... yep, sure are.... Missed that... Then I guess the answer would be ... 40 years ago (with C) declaring variables as global made sense because stack space was limited -- now it is simply an anachronism you may find referenced in some very very old documentation.

Comment: Avoid that bits include please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no difference.  If your sample size is small (you submitted both solutions once or twice), perhaps you were on the border of Time Limit Exceeded vs not, and just got lucky sometimes.